# focusing with # doesn't work as expected, why?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, hyperlink, focus

I set the link on my top-menu SOLUTION button to be this one "http://www.atracore.com/index.php#solutions" and the #solutions is set on the title "CORE TECH SOLUTIONS" on the second half of the page.

But when clicking the SOLUTIONS link, the focus is not correct, it's a couple of lines higher (please check this screenshots: http://i57.tinypic.com/dr4ho7.jpg )

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your page is loading content after HTML has rendered.

When I initially click on the link, it DOES go to your #solutions anchor properly.  However, after the page loads, It looks like some javascript loads your graphics and pushes the page down.  The browser cannot compensate for that and will not dynamically update your page.

What you need to do is setup the element of the dynamic content with the height of your graphics so the HTML render knows how large your dynamic content is, and it will allow your # anchor to go to the right place.  If you cannot do that, you may need to do some javacript to move the page to the right spot after loading the dynamic graphics.

Comment: please tell me how could I setup the element of the dynamic content with the height of the graphics?

Comment: Do you know how tall your graphics is?  If you do, set the height of the element of the containing graphics.

Comment: Hmm, actually, there are other errors with how it is made.  I don't really have time to get into how to fix it though.  If you resize the browser window, your graphics doesn't resize until the picture changes.  At that point you can see the graphics changing push the HTML content around.

Comment: do you mean the slider graphics? I think they are 452px height each. i really don't know how could I set the height, because I didn't create the Wordpress theme :( can that be done through CSS, or I should edit some other files? please give me some advice, thanks a lot!

Comment: oh I see, you're totally right, I didn't see that until now... maybe if you could tell me just how to fix something so that the "focusing" works all right

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the element "slider-cycle".  Its height setting is being controlled by your Dynamic JS for loading and changing the graphics.  I currently don't have enough time to look into it further though.

Comment: hi Nelson :) is there any chance you could help me today? or at least tell me what that javascript should do more exactly - and where should i insert it?

Comment: I looked into it and I'm not really keen on reverse-engineering someone else's JS script to work it out.  It may be better to contact the author of the script to figure it out.